# Subtract radio button values from budget

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In an budget game the user has an amount of money (120 billion) and he can click on radio buttons. On each click the values of radio buttons will be subtracted from the amount in order to display the amount of savings. It works in the fiddle but doesnt work on the website:

Here is the JS-code:

```
$("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
var total = 120000000;
$("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
    total -= parseFloat($(this).val());
});
var total2 = 120000000 - total; 
$("#totalSum").html(total2);
});
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fw27291a/5/

Here is the website: http://labs.tageswoche.ch/budget/budget.html

Comment: if only I had that. \*sigh\*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the script is ok in your website.

In the **website** please check the **value** atribute in all the checkbox. Some of them dont have any values resulting in returning **NaN**.

```
$("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
   var total = 120000000;
   $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
     //**************this will print some NaN Values   
      alert(parseFloat($(this).val()));
     //**************this will print some NaN Values   

      total -= parseFloat($(this).val());

   });

   $("#totalSum").html(total);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, so I have to add all values before it works properly, I didnt know that.

Answer (score 0):

`totalValue` is a `div` not an `input`: you have to write: `$("#totalSum").html(total);`

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fw27291a/12/

Comment: sorry I posted the wrong fiddle. It works in the fiddle, but doesnt work on the website. What do I have to change?